# datatable apply filter on groups only if a given row exists in the group

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, datatable, nested

I am trying to apply a filter to a group in a `datatable` only if a certain value exists. If it doesn't exist, the filter is not applicable and all the rows of the group are retained. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860548/filtering-rows-in-a-group-based-on-group-properties)

I am looking for a data table version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506772/dplyr-filter-on-value-only-if-another-value-exists-in-the-group-in-the-same-colu) answer, if possible, but with some additional criteria.

Firstly, I tried the following:

```
test <- data.table(grp=c(1,1,1,10,10,10,12,12), c=c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "c","a","b"))
test[test[, .I[c=="a" | all(c!="a")], by = grp]$V1]
```

Suggestions to improve are welcome.

Additional criteria that I am trying to incorporate is to check whether grp belongs to another list. If it belongs to the list, the filter is applicable

```
lst <- c("1", "8")
test[test[, .I[(c=="a" & grp %in% lst) | all(c!="a")], by = grp]$V1]
```

Here, the filter applies only to grp value 1 and not to 12 as it does not exist in lst. Instead of returning all rows with grp value 12, it is dropping them entirely. Obviously, it is wrong and I would like to know how to incorporate the condition.

Expected result:

```
   grp c
1:   1 a
2:  10 b
3:  10 c
4:  10 c
5:  12 a
6:  12 b
```

For grp=1, it exists in lst and hence filter is applied.
For grp=10, no filter is needed as there is not a single row with c="a"
For grp=12, filter is applicable BUT as it doesn't belong to lst, the filter is not used.

Thanks

Comment: Based on your conditino, why shsould it return the group for 12.  You are doing `grp %in% lst` and this is not the case for 12

Comment: Your `lst <- c("1", "8")` and it doesn't include 12

Comment: I added one more condition to return cases where the group is not included inlst

Comment: Yes, I wanted to apply the filter only to grp="1" and not to grp="12" although they both have  c="a". I know I am wrong there. In my mind, it is like nested-if conditions but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: Please check the code below.  I posted two cases.  May be one of them helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using the same logic.  In addition to the OP's logic, add an `OR` (`|`) condition to return all the rows of group that are not included in the 'lst' object

```
test[test[, all(c != 'a')| (c == 'a' & .BY %in% lst)|
          !.BY %in% lst, by = grp]$V1]
```

-output

```
#  grp c
#1:   1 a
#2:  10 b
#3:  10 c
#4:  10 c
#5:  12 a
#6:  12 b
```

---

Or we can use an `if/else` condition

```
test[test[, .I[if(!.BY %in% lst) TRUE else
     (c=="a" & grp %in% lst) | all(c!="a")] , by = grp]$V1]
```

Comment: Could the above behave differently when the column 'grp' is a `factor` and when it is a `character`? Seems like it is making a difference. Thanks!

Comment: @K_D It is better to convert to `character` cass

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a helper column:

```
> test <- data.table(grp=c(1,1,1,10,10,10,12,12), c=c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "c","a","b"))
> lst <- c(1, 8)
> dtFiltered <- test[, filtera := !all(c != "a") & (grp %in% lst), by = grp][!filtera | c == "a"][, filtera := NULL]
```